# Account roles are not getting created on enabling the account as a partner

Tags: account, contact, user, partner-communities, roles

I have an integration project that is stuck due to the limitation I am facing with my Salesforce instance. On enabling Account as a Partner, the roles are not getting assigned. I can't see the role field when I go to the related contact and opt for creating a user.

What can be done to ensure that the roles are available for opting when I chose to create a Partner User from Contact.

FYI - I already have a fixed number of roles assigned from the Community Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of creating the Partner user from Contact, role will not be available.

After creating the user, role is available which will be 'Account Name + Partner User' format. By default Partner User role is assigned. Though you can change this.

Here MNC Vendor is Account Name

[image: Partner role]
There will be three roles for Partner users based on your settings.

- Executive
- Manager
- User

Refer [Partner User Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partner_roles_overview.htm&type=5)

> When you enable the first external user on a partner account, a user role hierarchy is created for that account. This role hierarchy rolls up to the account owner (typically, the channel manager). The three roles in this hierarchy are Partner User, Partner Manager, or Partner Executive. When you create contacts on the partner account and convert them to external users, assign one of these roles to them.

Comment: Hello @Santanu,
Thanks for the response. 
Just to be clear, Does this role assignment is based on "Account Name + Partner User/Manager/Executive" format, or "Account Name + User/Manager/Executive" format.

Also, what among the following is assigned by default, since we can't opt for the role at the start.

Thanks Again!

Comment: It will be `Account Name + Partner User/Manager/Executive` format, by default Partner User role is assigned

Comment: Hi Santanu, is there any way I can see that role created in Salesforce as soon as the Account is enabled as a partner. Still receiving the error that the role is not one of the specified values, even after passing the role in an "Account Name + Partner Manager" format.

Comment: In short, I have to make sure that such a role exists in salesforce.

Comment: role will be created after the user is created

Comment: @SantanuBoral I created the user but I see only one role in the dropdown i.e. Account Name Partner User. I am not able to see the Partner Manager and Partner Executive role in the dropdown when editing the user.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite an old topic, but I think the roles are not created because of the "**Minimize the number of roles created, which improves performance by cutting down processing loads**" checkbox enabled. Here's the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5). This option might be found in Setup -> Sharing Settings. In single words, if it's enabled, then all partner users get the common partner role. If there's a second partner user created for the parent Account, only after that this account gets its own partner user roles depending on the chosen [Number of partner roles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_default_roles.htm&type=5).